# aws terraform jenkins declarative pipeline access denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, terraform

I have a declarative jenkins pipeline in which I am trying to deploy terraform but I'm recieving the following error:

```
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
status code: 403, request id: requestid, host id: hostid
```

The pipeline has the credentials as env vars

```
pipeline{
        agent any
        options {
            ansiColor('xterm')
        }   
        environment {
            AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="eu-west-1"
            AWS_ROLE_ACCOUNT="*accountnumber*"
            AWS_ROLE="*rolename*"
            TERRAFORM_REPO="*https://github.com/repo.git*"
            TERRAFORM_REPO_BRANCH="develop"
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=credentials('JENKINS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=credentials('JENKINS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
        }
        stages{
           stage {
              steps {
                download code from git
              }
           }            
           stage ('testing aws local credentials'){
                steps {
                    script {
                        if ( params.ACTION == 'create') {
                            echo "${params.ACTION}"
                            echo "Let's CREATE some infra"
                            sh "cd folder && TF_LOG=debug terraform init && terraform workspace new ${params.environment} && terraform workspace select ${params.environment} "
                            sh "cd folder && terraform plan"
                            input message: "Apply plan?"
                            sh "cd folder && terraform appy -auto-approve" 
                        } else {
                            echo "${params.ACTION}"
                            echo "Let's DESTROY some infra"
                            sh "cd folder terraform destroy -auto-approve"
                        
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

The tf.state file is stored in a bucket that is in a different account than the account in which the infrastructure is going to be deployed in AWS.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = var.region
  profile = "profileA"

}
data "terraform_remote_state" "remoteState" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket  = "bucketname"
    key     = "env:/${terraform.workspace}/name.tfstate"
    region  = "region"
    encrypt = "true"
    profile = "profileB"
  }
}
```

The aws CLI works fine, so I think that this is related with terraform.

So I have tried to create an AWS config file that includes the profiles and roles of the accounts on which terraform operates in the home of the jenkins user, without a credentials file, since I don't want the credentials to be stored in a file, but the pipeline to read them from the pipeline environment.

I don't know if the problem comes from the fact that the jenkins pipeline can't use two AWS profiles, but I don't know why, it never gave me problems before.

I'm not using the terraform plugin for Jenkins and the permissions of the user are correct (I have tested them).

I have tried using the jenkins withCredentials without success.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is done in `stages`? Which commands are you using? Are you trying to assume a role or something else?

Comment: I have updated the info

Comment: And I'm guessing there is a `backend.tf` or backend config somewhere in the repo that you are cloning?

Comment: No, the tf.state is in S3 and I reference them with a data block in terraform

Comment: You could use `role_arn` instead of the `profile` in the `data` source if the role is used to access the S3 bucket where the state is stored. https://www.terraform.io/language/settings/backends/s3#assume-role-configuration

Comment: I'm using STS to assume the role that the user needs so that is not an option to me

Comment: Ok, so then I don't understand how would you use two different profiles if you don't create them. The AWS environment variables for Terraform need to have a name that starts with `AWS_*` so the Jenkins ones wouldn't be read unless you told Terraform where to look for them.

Comment: The profiles exists in the $(JENKINS_USER_HOME)/.aws/config file. If I execute terraform out of Jenkins, terraform works file. I haven't seen any env variables but access_key and the secret_key. What variables do I need?